# What do I call this shaft that drives the rubber stopper into the glass vial in a vial stoppering machine?

Tags: terminology

I'm translating a Russian text about a drug product manufacturing process. The text mentions briefly the vial stoppering machine, in which rubber stoppers are first fed into the hopper and then directed towards vials, and a **[пуансон](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%EF%F3%E0%ED%F1%EE%ED)** drives the stopper into the vial. Multitran [provides multiple options](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%EF%F3%E0%ED%F1%EE%ED) for how to translate this "пуансон". It's basically some shaft-like member.

I googled and found a [description of some stoppering machine in Russian](http://www.findpatent.ru/patent/231/2319659.html), and it has a diagram, with "пуансон" under number 60:

> [image]

The text there says that the axle (59) rotates, making the cam (58) rotate and push this.. plunger\piston\punch member (?) towards the vial and drive the rubber stopper into the vial.

I'm unsure which word to use for this part.

Comment: A camshaft? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camshaft

Comment: @am304 - I've just googled for "vial stoppering camshaft" and it does not seem to fit.. no mention of "camshaft driving the rubber stopper inside the vial"

Comment: Well, that's kind of what it is, except in reverse if I understand correctly. I guess you could also call it a "corking lever", but that doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: @am304 - it must be "lever" then, since "camshaft" is the shaft to which cams are fastened, and not the thingy that actually does the job of pushing the stopper in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A camshaft is rotating a cam that is part of the shaft. It seems the cam acts on a roller, fixed on a push-rod, and so pushes down the push-rod in the guider.
I think the push-rod pushes the rubber down with a punch cap.

I think push-rod is the word you're searching for if you're talking about part 60.
Plunger may be a synonym, but I think of a kind of pump when hearing that term.

Comment: +1, Pushrod is the word that sprang immediately to my mind also.